# One hot encoder Pyspark for multiple columns with each columns having different number of categorical labels

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, one-hot-encoding

I'm new to pyspark and I need to display all unique labels that are present in different categorical columns

I have a pyspark dataframe with the following columns

| ID | cat_col1 | cat_col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | C |
| 2 | B | A |

I want the final output to look like

| ID | cat_col1_A | cat_col1_B | cat_col1_C | cat_col2_A | cat_col2_B | cat_col2_C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

```
categorical_columns = ['cat_col1 ','cat_col2']
# The index of string values multiple columns
indexers = [
    StringIndexer(inputCol=c, outputCol="{0}_indexed".format(c)).setHandleInvalid("keep")
    for c in categorical_columns
]

# The encode of indexed values multiple columns
encoders = [OneHotEncoder(dropLast=False,inputCol=indexer.getOutputCol(), outputCol="{0}_encoded".format(indexer.getOutputCol())) for indexer in indexers]


pipeline = Pipeline(stages=indexers + encoders) #+[assembler])
model=pipeline.fit(temp_df).transform(temp_df)
model.display()
```

The OP is something like this

| ID | Cat_col_1_A_indexed | Cat_col_1_B_indexed | Cat_col_1_unknown_indexed | Cat_col_2_A_indexed | Cat_col_2_C_indexed | Cat_col_2_unknown_indexed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Only the unique labels in each column are displayed. I want to display the unique labels present in all categorical columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i could think of a couple of ways, and both of them require unpivoting the data.

- create distinct column names within the dataframe
- create column names using distinct values from all categories (requires a `collect`)

within dataframe

```py
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('attr', 
               func.array(*[func.struct(func.lit(c).alias('c_name'), 
                                        func.col(c).alias('c_val')
                                        ) for c in data_sdf.drop('id').columns]
                          )
               ). \
    selectExpr('id', 'inline(attr)'). \
    withColumn('all_val', func.collect_set('c_val').over(wd.partitionBy(func.lit(1)))). \
    select('*', func.explode('all_val').alias('all_val_exp')). \
    withColumn('pivot_col', func.concat_ws('_', 'c_name', 'all_val_exp')). \
    groupBy('id'). \
    pivot('pivot_col'). \
    agg(func.max(func.col('c_val') == func.col('all_val_exp')).cast('int')). \
    show()

# +---+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
# | id|cat_col1_A|cat_col1_B|cat_col1_C|cat_col2_A|cat_col2_B|cat_col2_C|
# +---+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
# |  1|         1|         0|         0|         0|         0|         1|
# |  2|         0|         1|         0|         1|         0|         0|
# +---+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

using list to create required column names

```py
cats = data_sdf.select(func.array_distinct(func.flatten(func.collect_list(func.array('cat_col1', 'cat_col2'))))).collect()[0][0]

fnl_cat_cols = sorted([x+'_'+y for x in data_sdf.drop('id').columns for y in cats])

# ['cat_col1_A',
#  'cat_col1_B',
#  'cat_col1_C',
#  'cat_col2_A',
#  'cat_col2_B',
#  'cat_col2_C']

data_sdf. \
    withColumn('attr', 
               func.array(*[func.struct(func.lit(c).alias('c_name'), 
                                        func.col(c).alias('c_val')
                                        ) for c in data_sdf.drop('id').columns]
                          )
               ). \
    selectExpr('id', 'inline(attr)'). \
    withColumn('pivot_col', func.concat_ws('_', 'c_name', 'c_val')). \
    groupBy('id'). \
    pivot('pivot_col', values=fnl_cat_cols). \
    agg(func.lit(1)). \
    fillna(0, subset=fnl_cat_cols). \
    show()

# +---+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
# | id|cat_col1_A|cat_col1_B|cat_col1_C|cat_col2_A|cat_col2_B|cat_col2_C|
# +---+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
# |  1|         1|         0|         0|         0|         0|         1|
# |  2|         0|         1|         0|         1|         0|         0|
# +---+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

---

the first approach seems memory intensive given the 2 explodes. so, you can try the second approach which seems lighter of the two.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my 2 cents:

Create a dataframe, extract all the distinct values/create a list of distinct values. Iterate over those values and extract the values based on the column values

```
data = [
    [1,'A','C'],
    [2,'B','A']
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data,['ID','cat_col1','cat_col2'])

df.show()

import pyspark.sql.functions as F

# If you want to create columns which are only present in the cat_col1 & cat_col2
# distinct_col1_values = df.select('cat_col1').distinct().rdd.map(lambda x:x[0]).collect()
# distinct_col2_values = df.select('cat_col2').distinct().rdd.map(lambda x:x[0]).collect()

distinct_col1_values=distinct_col2_values=['A','B','C']

# You can club the 2 withColumn statements in a single one, if required.
for value1 in distinct_col1_values:
    df = df.withColumn(f"cat_col1_{value1}",F.expr(f"""CASE WHEN cat_col1 ='{value1}' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END"""))

for value1 in distinct_col2_values:
    df = df.withColumn(f"cat_col2_{value1}",F.expr(f"""CASE WHEN cat_col2 ='{value1}' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END"""))
            
df = df.drop(*['cat_col1','cat_col2'])  

df.show()
```

Check the below image for input and output:
[image]